# Django middleware: Isn't a middleware module error

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am using the middleware provided in https://gist.github.com/426829 to do cross site scripting.

However, when I add the middleware to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`, I get the error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: isn't a middleware module.

My `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` looks like this:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
                      'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
                      'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
                      'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
                      'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
                      'TempMiddleware',)
```

I have not changed any code in the gist. `process_request` and `process_response` methods are there. I am on Ubuntu running the latest versions of Python and Django.

Comment: Show us your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting.

Comment: MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'TempMiddleware',
)

Comment: Its able to locate the middleware module though. As error reads - TempMiddleware isnt a middleware module.

Comment: yes. importing works in the shell.

Comment: What's `TempMiddleware` - the gist refers to `XsSharing`?

Comment: Got it. Should have provided class name, rather than module name. Thanks for helping.

But now getting "Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Comment: looks from the gist like you need to set `XS_SHARING_ALLOWED_ORIGINS`, whatever that means.

Comment: @DominicRodger Thanks. But solved the issue. Middleware I was using does not specify everything. I had to modify it to use allowed request headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's `TempMiddleware`? The name of the module, or the name of the class? As you can see with the other entries, you need the fully-qualified Python path of the actual class. If `TempMiddleware` is the name of the module, you need `TempMiddleware.MyMiddlewareClass` (and you should really follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions) - and if it's the name of the class, you need `my_module.TempMiddleware`.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that now.

But even though now backend is working, I am still getting following error. 

Origin http://127.0.0.1 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

`TempMiddleware` is not importable. It's the name of the class, you must put the entire import path.

E.g:

```
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'
```

and not

```
'AuthenticationMiddleware'
```

So if your class is in app_name/middleware.py, it should be

```
app_name.middlaware.TempMiddleware
```

---

It just mean that in your settings file, the variable `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` contains a list of modules in which one of the listed module is not a middleware.

Possible causes:

- you added a middleware that doesn't declare middleware methods: fix that by removing the last middleware you added
- you added a correct middleware but forget to put a coma at the end of the name, so strings are concatenated and it make django thinks 2 middlewares are in fact one: fix that by adding the missing coma

Comment: Both things you have mentioned dont seem to be issue.

Comment: Then answer to @Dominic Rodger

Comment: Posted the setting above. Let me know what could be wrong here. Very new to Django. :)